# How to add node run option --max-http-header-size and add name to pm2 start command

Tags: node.js, pm2

**How would I start a `pm2` process with the `—max-http-header-size` node option, as well as name the process.**

I have a server with multiple micro-services, one of the services is a web scraper.

This web scraper accepts requests with headers over the `nodejs` default `8kb` limit. So, to run my app locally have to add the `--max-http-header-size` node option.

I've cloned my app to the server, but don't know how to set `--max-http-header-size`, nor do I know how to name the process within the `pm2 start` command.

So far my attempts have looked like this.

```
// this sets the name, but I don't know how to add the option `--max-http-header-size`
pm2 start npm --name "{REPONAME}" -- start
```

```
pm2 start node --name "scraper" --max-http-header-size 15000 app.js
```

```
pm2 start node --max-http-header-size 15000 app.js -- --name "scraper"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called environment variables! You can pass environment variables to pm2 using a file that loads your server like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
      {
        name: "myapp",
        script: "./app.js",
        watch: true,
        node_args: "--max-http-header-size=16000"
      }
  ]
}
```

Here's more about it too:
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/

Comment: Did not work for me.  What worked was this:  https://technorach.wordpress.com/2020/05/17/node-max-http-header-size/

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer by David Harvey did not work for me as of Node 16.  Instead, I had to use node_args, something like this:

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "myapp",
    "script"      : "./app.js",
    "node_args": "--max-http-header-size=256000",
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production",
    }
  }]
}
```